# How to perform Or Query using Django-Filter

Tags: django, django-filter, django-filters

```
class MyFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = {
            'field': ['exact',  'isnull'],
        }
```

Now How do I filter this ?field=1&field__isnull=True ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it by adding a custom field.

```py
def filter_field_or_null(queryset, value):
    return queryset.filter(
        Q(field=value) | Q(field__isnull=True)
    )


class MyFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    field_or_null = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(
        queryset=SomeModel.objects.all(),
        action=filter_field_or_null
    )

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

Answer (score 1):

you can view [Customize filtering with Filter.method](http://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/usage.html?highlight=ModelChoiceFilter#customize-filtering-with-filter-method) with django-filter 1.1.0, and code can be as below

```
    class MyFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
        field = NumberFilter(method='field_exact_or_isnull_filter')

        class Meta:
            model = MyModel
            fields = [field]

        def field_exact_or_isnull_filter(self, queryset, name, value):
            return queryset.filter(
                Q(field=1) | Q(field=None)
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

I am confused, your question is how to perform OR query, however, your example is "&" (this usually means AND) if you want to make OR condition, you could use Q object

such as:

```
Q(field=1) | Q(field__isnull=True)
```

please refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q for more information.

Greet.

Comment: Can you please answer this in reference to `Django-Filter`.

Comment: @vaibhavjain, sorry, I didn't get your point correctly... it should also use Q object to combine OR condition ...

Comment: @zhaorong - it's not entirely clear in the OP, but `?field=1&field__isnull=True` is a URL query string. `&` is just the separator between the key-value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

For your reference use [Django Filter](http://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#the-model) doc

May be following example useful

```
from django.db import models
import django_filters

class Mymodel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    field2 = models.IntegerField(null=True)


class MyFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    field1__iexact = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='iexact')
    field1__isnull = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='isnull')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['field1']
```

Comment: My question is to perform filter on the same field not on different.

Comment: So you are saying if I do `?field__iexact=<some_id>&field__isnull=` then I will get `some_id plus all the null objects` ?? I don't think so. As first it will filter the queryset for `some_id` then for `null` objects and return the `ANed` of the query. And I want `Or` So please see the answer submitted by me.